# How to display string from Latin-Extended-A charset

Tags: java, string, unicode

I can't display string, which contains Latin-Extended-A chars in an appropriate way.

I have tried getting bytes with different Unicode and creating new String with new Unicode.

If you have string "ăăăăăăăăă". How can i output it in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java supports `unicode` characters. If you have:

```
String x = "ăăăăăăăăă";
System.out.println(x);
```

You'll get

```
ăăăăăăăăă
```

If you get question marks or funky looking characters, then it's most likely not a problem with java or the code, but with the fonts on your computer not supporting it.